# How can I periodically process the next item of a list box?

Tags: delphi, timer, listbox

I have a list of proxy addresses in a TListBox (1.2.42.x.2.4:42, 2.4.1.x.1.2.x.2:60, etc.) that I use with TIdHTTP. When a button is clicked, I fetch a given URL using the selected proxy:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  I := Listbox1.ItemIndex;
  if I <> -1 then
  begin
    S := Listbox1.Items[I];
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Fetch(S, ':');
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := StrToInt(S);
    try
      IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout:=strtoint(form1.Edit1.Text); // ZMAAN AŞIMI
      IdHTTP1.Get(Edit4.Text);                         // POST GET
      MessageDlg('Ok.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0); // TAMAMLANDI.
    except
      MessageDlg('Error.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0);   // HATA VERDİ.
      IdHTTP1.Disconnect;   // ÖLDÜR.
    end;
  end;
end;
```

After clicking the button, I want my program to automatically do the same as above, but with ListBox1.Items[1], then ListBox1.Items[2], and so on.

I think I could use a TTimer for this, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Here's one way:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  I := Listbox1.ItemIndex;
  if I <> -1 then
  begin
    S := Listbox1.Items[I];
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := Fetch(S, ':');
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := StrToInt(S);
     try
      IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout:=strtoint(form1.Edit1.Text); // ZMAAN AŞIMI
      IdHTTP1.Get(Edit4.Text);                         // POST GET
      MessageDlg('Ok.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0); // TAMAMLANDI.
    except
      MessageDlg('Error.', mtinformation,[mbOK],0);   // HATA VERDİ.
      IdHTTP1.Disconnect;   // ÖLDÜR.
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  try
    ListBox1Click(nil);
    if ListBox1.ItemIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 then
      ListBox1.ItemIndex := ListBox1.ItemIndex + 1
    else
      ListBox1.ItemIndex := -1;
  finally
    // To stop after only one loop through all items, as you asked in your comment:
    Timer1.Enabled := (ListBox1.ItemIndex > -1);
  end;
end;
```

I'd personally move almost all of the code from the `ListBox1Click` event into it's own standalone method that you could call from either the `ListBox.OnClick` event or the `Timer.OnTimer` event easily. You could pass in the `ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]` as a parameter to that method. It would make your code much cleaner, IMO.

Comment: very thanks. Label1.caption:= Successful? Label2.caption:= Unsuccessful?  how do I? so, 4 successful, 5 unsuccesfull, 2 Timeout? And only one loop..?

Comment: Use a `TMemo` instead. For each one that you try, add a line to the memo. `Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Try %d: %s', [i, StatusMessage]));`, where `StatusMessage` is whatever you want to display (`Successful`, `Unsuccessful`, `TimeOut`). Do that where you're using the two `MessageDlg` calls now in the `ListBox1Click` event.

Comment: [Error] Unit1.pas(142): Undeclared identifier: 'StatusMessage'  Error :$

Comment: where StatusMessage is whatever you want to display +++

you want +++

you want and you make it whatever you want it to be

Comment: Please *read* what I wrote. Declare `StatusMessage` as a string variable; assign it `Successful`, `Unsuccessful`, or whatever, and **then** display it. `StatusMessage` is the name of a variable that will, well, contain a **status message** that you can  then show the user in place of the `MessageDlg` calls you're showing now (as I wrote in my last comment).

Comment: I understand you. But.. Only one loops?

Comment: As it is now, it only loops once. When it reaches the last item, it sets the `ListBox1.ItemIndex` back to -1, and your `ListBox1Click` event already checks for `I <> -1`. When it hits `-1` again, disable the timer and leave it disabled (by setting `Timer1.Enabled := False;`). I edited the `Timer1Timer` event in my code to do just that - leave the timer disabled if the `ItemIndex` is -1.